# boost::asio::streambuf with wchar_t

Tags: c++, unicode, buffer, boost-asio, iostream

I am trying to do the following with wide characters:

```
boost::asio::streambuf io_streambuf_;
std::iostream io_stream(io_streambuf_);
```

I tried this but got a bunch of compiler errors :

```
boost::asio::streambuf io_streambuf_;
std::wiostream wio_stream(io_streambuf_);
```

I know that streambuf is `<char>`, how do I the same but with a `wchar_t` buffered stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

boost::asio::streambuf is a typedef for boost::asio::basic_streambuf. The default template implementation of basic_streambuf is:

```
template<typename Allocator = std::allocator<char>>
class basic_streambuf :
  noncopyable
```

So what you'd need to do is declare:

```
boost::asio::basic_streambuf<std::allocator<wchar_t>> io_streambuf_;
std::wiostream wio_stream(io_streambuf_);
```

Note: I haven't tested this - but that's the core of your problem.